# "Ein Tag nach Silvester" für "Neujahrstag"?

Tags: usage

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Maik Barthel war **einen Tag nach Silvester** schon wieder unterwegs. Im Winter, wenn viele Ligen in Europa Pause machen, haben Berater Hochkonjunktur, ...

Die Verwendung von "einen Tag nach Silvester" kommt mir merkwürdig vor, denn schließlich hat der Tag einen eigenen Namen, und zwar **Neujahrstag**. Gibt es irgenwelche Gründe, wie im Ausschnitt zu formulieren?

Comment: War Silvester vielleicht irgendein besonderes Ereignis (abgesehen vom Ende des Jahres), das vorher erwähnt wurde?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Nein, gar nicht.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neujahr (oder Neujahrstag) ist ein normaler arbeitsfreier Feiertag. Silvester ist ein unechter Feiertag, an dem lange gefeiert wird, oft mit ausgiebigem Alkoholkonsum.

Die Betonung auf *einen Tag nach Silvester* statt Neujahr könnte sich darauf beziehen. Im Sinne von: Toll, er schon wieder unterwegs, obwohl er gestern so feierte und eigentlich ausschlafen sollte/wollte.

Wäre er an Neujahr unterwegs, ist es vergleichbar zu normaler Sonntagsarbeit.

Answer (score 0):

Wir wissen zwar, dass Neujahr nach Silvester kommt, aber hier geht es um die Zeit, die vergangenen ist. Einen Tag danach. Darauf liegt der Fokus.